# How to return child class's object when function return type is parent class?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

I guess that Java is possible to substitute child class's object for parent class's object. I want to do it in c++.

I'm trying to do it as following. However, I got "error: return type 'Food' is an abstract class" error. How can I fix it?

**Before** it works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Food {
    public:
        virtual void SetPrice(int myprice) = 0;
        int GetPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    protected:
        int price;
};

class Fruit : public Food {
    public:
        void SetPrice(int myprice) {
            price = myprice - 20;
        }
};

class Fish : public Food {
    public:
        void SetPrice(int myprice) {
            price = myprice / 2;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Food *pFood;
    Fruit myFruit;
    Fish myFish;

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "fruit") == 0) {
        pFood = &myFruit;
    } else {
        pFood = &myFish;
    }

    pFood->SetPrice(100);
    cout << pFood->GetPrice() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**After** class definition is omitted. it doesn't work:

```
Food getFoodObject(string type)
{
    if (strcmp(type, "fruit") == 0) {
        Fruit myFruit;
        return &myFruit; // I don't want to write 2 lines. I want to return the above line. This is my another question...
    }

    Fish myFish;
    return &myFish;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Food *pFood;

    pFood = getFoodObject(argv[1])

    pFood->SetPrice(100);
    cout << pFood->GetPrice() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Update 1

Thanks to many advices, my issue was solved. I need to use c++11 so I use unique_ptr instead of make_unique.

```
std::unique_ptr<Food> getFoodObject(string type)
{
    if (type == "fruit") {
        return std::unique_ptr<Fruit>(new Fruit);
    }   
   return std::unique_ptr<Fish>(new Fish);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::unique_ptr<Food> pFood = getFoodObject(argv[1]);

    pFood->SetPrice(100);
    cout << pFood->GetPrice() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

@dlasalle mentioned about Boost library. I will post update after I can use Boost's smart pointer as my note.

Comment: So do you have 2 questions or one? :P

Comment: `pFood` is a pointer. `getFoodObject` returns an object, not pointer. In Java almost everything are implicit pointers. So you should work with pointers as well to achieve what you want

Comment: Post real code! ``strcmp(type, "fruit") `` will not compile with ``string type``.

Comment: @manni66 That error would have been below the error about the abstractness of the return type. Seems reasonable for the OP to fix errors in descending order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return by pointer type or reference to the base class, not by value.  This is required since your base class is an abstract class and you cannot instantiate a abstract class.  That said you can't just do

```
Food* getFoodObject(string type)
{
    if (strcmp(type, "fruit") == 0) {
        Fruit myFruit;
        return &myFruit; // I don't want to write 2 lines. I want to return the above line. This is my another question...
    }

    Fish myFish;
    return &myFish;
}
```

Because then you are returning a pointer to a function local object and as soon as the function exits the object is destroyed leaving you with a dangling pointer.  What we can do is change the code to use a `std::unique_ptr` (using a smart pointer as it manages the memory for us) and then you could have something like

```
std::unique_ptr<Food> getFoodObject(string type)
{
    if (type == "fruit") {
        return std::unique_ptr<Fruit>(new Fruit);
        // or in C++14 return std::make_unique<Fruit>();
    }
    return std::unique_ptr<Fish>(new Fish);
    // or in C++14 return std::make_unique<Fish>();
}
```

And you would call the function like

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::unique_ptr<Food> pFood = getFoodObject(argv[1])

    pFood->SetPrice(100);
    cout << pFood->GetPrice() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Also note that `if (strcmp(type, "fruit") == 0)` is invalid.  `strcmp` deals with c-strings, not `std::string`.  To compare a `std::string` you can just use `==` like `if (type == "fruit")`

Comment: You're missing a couple of `return`s there.

Comment: @themiurge Thanks.  overwrote them on accident

Comment: It requires C++14 ) Obviously he don't understand how memory works in C++, as he returns pointers at stack allocated objects.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have to use c++11. I'm looking into it. I will post my result soon.

Comment: @zono to make it work under C++11 you have to replace `std::make_unique<Fish>` with something like `std::unique_prt<Fish>...`

Comment: @zono If you have to use C++11 change `return std::make_unique<type>();` to `return std::unique_ptr<type>(new type);`

Answer (score 2):

In Java you're always returning a reference (a glorified pointer), however in C++ you have the option of returning the object by value, by reference, or by pointer. Polymorphism in C++ is only allowable via references and pointers.

By returning the parent class by value, you end up with [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), but you also end up with an instance of an abstract class, which is not valid (thus the compiler error).

You want to do something like this:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<Food> getFoodObject(string type)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Food> ptr;
    if (type.compare("fruit") == 0) {
        ptr.reset(new Fruit());
    } else {
        ptr.reset(new Fish());
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

If you're not using c++11, you'll either need to use [boost](http://www.boost.org/)'s smart pointers or simply raw pointers.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm getting understand about polymorphism in c++.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pointer in c++. An abstract class cannot be instantiated, so you can't use the abstract base class as an instance. You can create the parent concrete class, and then use set a pointer of the base class to it.